# How To Use Laravel Factory For Objects ( Not Models )

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a Class Like This :

```html
class Ip
{

    public $ip;

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getIp()
    {
        return $this->ip;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $ip
     */
    public function setIp($ip)
    {
        $this->ip = $ip;
    }

}
```

and I Write a Factory For This :

```html
/** @var \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory $factory */
$factory->define(\Modules\FraudDetection\ObjectModels\Ip::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {

    return [
        'ip' => $faker->numerify('###.###.##.###')
    ];
});
```

But When i Want to Use That Factory , the result is null :

> {"ip":null}

I know If I Extend Model It Will Work . Is There Any Other Solution To use Factory without extending model ?

Comment: try $modelMock = Mockery::mock('App\Model'); and on your model factory call that class.

Comment: let me check mockery style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Searching a while, I Found This Solution

for Using Laravel Factory for Normal Objects ( Like My Ip Class Which is not extends Model )
you should copy Below codes to your Object **( in my example Ip class )**

```html
    /**
     * Ip constructor.
     * @param array $attributes
     */
    public function __construct($attributes = [])
    {
        foreach ($attributes as $key => $value) {
            $this->$key = $value;
        }
    }
    
    
        /**
     * Create a new Eloquent Collection instance.
     *
     * @param  array  $models
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection
     */
    public function newCollection(array $models = [])
    {
        return new Collection($models);
    }
```

now you can use Laravel Factory Like always ( which is exist in laravel document )